# Dispatch Instrument doesn't support with iPhone5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instruments

When I try profile my application with dispatch instrument It says "This device doesn't support this instruments(dispatch)". It means, this feature is supported based on the devices or OS versions?[image]

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: How you opened the dispatch instruments ?

Comment: Product-> Profile -> dispatch see my another screen shot

Comment: Did you resolve the problem? I have the same problem. I try with iPhone5(8.3), iPhone6P(8.3), iPhone5(7.1) and every time had same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Apple's doc, it only works for OS X.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/DispatchInstrument/DispatchInstrument.html